# WTSEnumerateProcesses with socket and data struct

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp

I'm new with C++ Windows API and I've got few questions about using the `WTSEnumerateProcesses()` API.

My target: use `WTSEnumerateProcesses()`, take only the process list, put it in any kind of "list" or struct, convert the widechar to ANSI, and send it to a socket using Winsock.

That's my code below:

Winsock:

```cpp
int connect(char buffer[])
{
    PCSTR ip = "localhost";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    const char *sendbuf =buffer;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(ip, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    while (iResult > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

and the `WTSEnumerateProcesses()`:

```cpp
void GetProcesslist()
{
    vector<LPWSTR> v;         // no need to prepend std:: any more
    LPWSTR pProcessName;
    WTS_PROCESS_INFO* pWPIs = NULL;
    DWORD dwProcCount = 0;
    if (WTSEnumerateProcesses(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, NULL, 1, &pWPIs, &dwProcCount))
    {
        //Go through all processes retrieved
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwProcCount; i++)
        {
            pProcessName = pWPIs[i].pProcessName;
            v[i] = pProcessName;
            //contains(pProcessName);
            // process file name only, no path!
            //data = pProcessName;
            std::wcout << pProcessName << endl;
            //pWPIs[i].ProcessId = process ID
            //pWPIs[i].SessionId = session ID, if you need to limit it to the logged in user processes
            //pWPIs[i].pUserSid = user SID that started the process
        }
    }

    //Free memory
    if (pWPIs)
    {
        WTSFreeMemory(pWPIs);
        pWPIs = NULL;
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to understand how I can take the process list only, push it to any struct (like a list?) and send it correctly over the TCP socket, that is waiting to get a `const char[]` and not wide characters?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `std::vector` correctly in your `GetProcesslist()`.  You are trying to access elements you have not allocated any memory for.  And worse, you are storing pointers to data that you free before `GetProcesslist()` exits, leaving the vector containing dangling pointers (were you to access that vector outside of `GetProcesslist()`, which you are not doing yet).

Try something more like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::wstring> GetProcesslist()
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> v;
    WTS_PROCESS_INFO* pWPIs = NULL;
    DWORD dwProcCount = 0;

    if (WTSEnumerateProcesses(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, NULL, 1, &pWPIs, &dwProcCount))
    {
        //Go through all processes retrieved
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwProcCount; ++i)
        {
            LPWSTR pProcessName = pWPIs[i].pProcessName;
            v.push_back(pProcessName);
            // process file name only, no path!
            //data = pProcessName;
            std::wcout << pProcessName << endl;
            //pWPIs[i].ProcessId = process ID
            //pWPIs[i].SessionId = session ID, if you need to limit it to the logged in user processes
            //pWPIs[i].pUserSid = user SID that started the process
        }
        //Free memory
        WTSFreeMemory(pWPIs);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Then, I would suggest sending the data over the socket like this:

```c
int connect(const char buffer[], size_t buffersize)
{
    PCSTR ip = "localhost";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    const char *sendbuf = buffer;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(ip, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    while (buffersize > 0) {
        iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)buffersize, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

        sendbuf += iResult;
        buffersize -= iResult;
    }

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    while (iResult > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
std::vector<std::wstring> procs = GetProcesslist();
std::vector<char> buffer;

size_t size = sizeof(uint32_t);
for(const std::wstring &name : procs) {
    size += (sizeof(uint32_t) + WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, name.c_str(), name.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL));
}

buffer.resize(size);
char *ptr = buffer.data();

*reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(ptr) = htonl(procs.size());
ptr += sizeof(uint32_t);
for(const std::wstring &name : procs) {
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, name.c_str(), name.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL));
    *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(ptr) = htonl(len);
    ptr += sizeof(uint32_t);
    if (len > 0) {
        ptr += WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, name.c_str(), name.size(), ptr, len, NULL, NULL));
    }
}

connect(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

Or, if you absolutely cannot change the signature of `connect()` and must pass it a null-terminated C string, then try this:

```c
int connect(const char buffer[])
{
    PCSTR ip = "localhost";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    const char *sendbuf = buffer;
    sendbuflen = strlen(buffer);
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(ip, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    while (sendbuflen > 0) {
        iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, sendbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

        sendbuf += iResult;
        sendbuflen -= iResult;
    }

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    while (iResult > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
std::vector<std::wstring> procs = GetProcesslist();
std::ostringstream oss;

oss << procs.size() << "\x1";
for(const std::wstring &name : procs) {
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, name.c_str(), name.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (len > 0) {
        std::string s;
        s.resize(len);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, name.c_str(), name.size(), &s[0], len, NULL, NULL);
        oss << s;
    }
    oss << "\x1";
}

connect(oss.str().c_str());
```